# how to handle different spelling of column names when extracting data?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, extract

For this example i have 2 dataframes, the genre column in df1 is column 3 but in df2 it is column 2, also the header is slightly different. in my actual script i have to search the column names because the column location varies in each sheet it reads.

how do i recognise different header names as the same thing?

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'TITLE': ['The Matrix','Die Hard','Kill Bill'],
               'VENDOR ID': ['1234','4321','4132'],
               'GENRE(S)': ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Drama']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'TITLE': ['Toy Story','Shrek','Frozen'],
               'Genre': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Family'],
               'VENDOR ID': ['5678','8765','8576']})

column_names = ['TITLE','VENDOR ID','GENRE(S)']

appended_data = []

sheet1 = df1[df1.columns.intersection(column_names)]
appended_data.append(sheet1)
sheet2 = df2[df2.columns.intersection(column_names)]
appended_data.append(sheet2)

appended_data = pd.concat(appended_data, sort=False)

output:

        TITLE VENDOR ID   GENRE(S)
0  The Matrix      1234     Action
1    Die Hard      4321  Adventure
2   Kill Bill      4132      Drama
0   Toy Story      5678        NaN
1       Shrek      8765        NaN
2      Frozen      8576        NaN

desired output:

        TITLE VENDOR ID   GENRE(S)
0  The Matrix      1234     Action
1    Die Hard      4321  Adventure
2   Kill Bill      4132      Drama
0   Toy Story      5678  Animation
1       Shrek      8765  Adventure
2      Frozen      8576     Family
```

Comment: You need to provide us with the table you are getting as output and the table you want it to look like. [Read](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) about minimal and reproducible questions.

Comment: i can't show the output as it contains data i can't share. however, the output i get is a spreadsheet with column_names as the headings. the issue is, for example, the "GENRE(S)" column will contain data extracted from the source sheets that have a column called "GENRES(S)", however when a sheet has a column called "Genre" instead - the cells are empty because that column name doesn't match. the other issue is the columns aren't in the same order in the source sheets which is why i search the column name rather than column index.

Comment: A picture is worth a thousand words. Instead of describing it you must create input and intended output DUMMY data.

Comment: added examples to the post. if i can't specify the column names or their index numbers, is it still possible to extract the data?

Comment: That isn't reproducible. Have you read [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)? Please read that and then edit your question in a form that is reproducible.

Comment: ok i've redone the above with a trimmed down reproducible version

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for taking the time to do that. Asking a good questions is very important and now that you have posed a coherent question I was able to find a simple solution rather quickly:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'TITLE': ['The Matrix','Die Hard','Kill Bill'],
                'VENDOR ID': ['1234','4321','4132'],
                 'GENRE(S)': ['Action', 'Adventure', 'Drama']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'TITLE': ['Toy Story','Shrek','Frozen'],
                    'Genre': ['Animation', 'Adventure', 'Family'],
                'VENDOR ID': ['5678','8765','8576']})
```

**Simple way:**
We will use `.append()` below but for this to work, we need columns in `df1` and `df2` to match. In this case we'll simply replace `df2's` `'Genre'` to `'GENRE(S)'`

```
df2.columns = ['TITLE', 'GENRE(S)', 'VENDOR ID']

df3 = df1.append(df2)
print(df3)

    GENRE(S)       TITLE VENDOR ID
0     Action  The Matrix      1234
1  Adventure    Die Hard      4321
2      Drama   Kill Bill      4132
0  Animation   Toy Story      5678
1  Adventure       Shrek      8765
2     Family      Frozen      8576
```

**More elaborate:**
Now, for a single use case this works but there may be cases where you have many mismatched columns and/or have to do this repeatedly. Here is a solution using boolean indexing to find mismatched names, then `zip()` and `.rename()` to map the column names:

```
# RELOAD YOUR ORIGINAL DF'S 

df1_find = df1.columns[~df1.columns.isin(df2.columns)] # select col name that isnt in df2
df2_find = df2.columns[~df2.columns.isin(df1.columns)] # select col name that isnt in df1

zipped = dict(zip(df2_find, df1_find)) # df2_find as key, df1_find as value

df2.rename(columns=zipped, inplace=True) # map zipped dict to the column names

df3 = df1.append(df2)
print(df3)

    GENRE(S)       TITLE VENDOR ID
0     Action  The Matrix      1234
1  Adventure    Die Hard      4321
2      Drama   Kill Bill      4132
0  Animation   Toy Story      5678
1  Adventure       Shrek      8765
2     Family      Frozen      8576
```

Keep in mind:

1. this way of doing it assumes that both your df's have the same count
   of columns
2. this ALSO assumes that `df1` has your ideal column names which you
   will use against other `df`s to fix their column names

I hope this helps.